# Bolt accessories

Tags: generator, stator

What’s called an accessory that doesn't let the bolt to come out from cover and get lost after unscrewed? Many a times I lost bolts after unscrewing, but there’s an arrangement I’ve seen with which bolt remains within cover and doesn’t come out. Can u tell me name and detail of the same? Here I’m talking about generator stator terminal. Moreover by adding this accessory I also want to prepare a KAIZEN.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Using a small tray to keep removed bolts in is one way, adding a magnet can help... I always considered an apprenticeship as the training to be able to put something back together without having **anything** left over... If it came with it, then it had a purpose...

Answer (score 1):

It's called a "captured" bolt. One way to do it is by using something like this Starlock®, which you'd put the bolt in place, then put the Starlock® on the threads, which would hold it in place:

[image: https://www.bakfin.com/taiwan/]